Subtracting geometry and its mesh
Following two very old questions Subtracting Geometry, I would like to know how to subtract geometries,
while also subtracting meshes.
The current worfklow is like this:
1. Creating two objects

2.Subtract with a Boolean modifier and hide the sphere

3. Problem: Moving to a a mesh gives you the same result as before

This operation is a very important step in modelling. Do you have a solution to this problem?

The only way you can do that is by applying the modifier.

To clarify that, putting a boolean modifier on an object doesn't actually change the object's mesh, just the representation of it in Object mode. So going int Edit mode as you have in your last image will still show the original geometry of the object as it isn't actually modified until the modifier is applied.

what does "until the modifier is applied" mean? I thought, I applied it in image 2, didn't I?

As @lynx095 says below you have to apply the modifier to make the change in the mesh permanent. Blender modifiers don't make changes to meshes permanent until you apply them. This is so that you can change the settings at will without having to re-do everything if you aren't happy with the result.

First you need to apply the modifier in the modifiers tab by opening the dropdown menu next to the modifier name and clicking "apply".

Your resulting mesh will look like this:


You can also hover the mouse over the modifier on the panel until it has a thin blue outline and use Ctrl-a to apply it.
